# PNG image blurry in Chrome because of different rounding; what to do with it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, png

I have a Bootstrap site that uses its grid system and inside one of the columns, I've got a PNG image that fills this column, like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
    <div><img src="image.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" /></div>
</div>
```

My image contains text so I'd like to make it as crisp as possible. In all major browsers, the space left for the image is 526x331 px. The problem is that it is not exactly that pixels - it is something like 525.8 x 530.9 px. It seems that all browsers except Chrome round to the nearest pixel but Chrome rounds down. The result is that in Chrome, the PNG is rendered as 525x330 and blurry:

[image: Chrome blurry PNG]

Is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think Chrome Rounds down- for divs; however It may be different for images. 
can you use 100% width on the image and see?

```
  width: 50.6px; becomes   width: 51px;
```

here is a little test to prove that chrome doesn't round down. 
do you have to use an image?

- http://jsfiddle.net/E85s6/

Comment: Yes I do. My solution was to make the image 1px narrower so that Chrome is happy. Other browsers are 1px off but that is comparatively a much smaller problem.

Comment: yes actual pixel ... there is no reason to used sub-pixel sizes..  but interesting topic regardless

Comment: Well, I wasn't specifying any width for my image - it just had some natural dimensions (its size was 526x331 *on the disk*). So the pixel fractions were caused by Bootstrap which uses percent widths for grid columns and some auto-sizing for "responsive images". I didn't want to set pixel size for my image in HTML/CSS. The -1px trick is good enough for me, fortunately.